Best Strategy for Storing JWT and Refresh Tokens in a Multi-Client Architecture (Blazor, MAUI, GraphQL)
I am currently developing a system with an ASP.NET Core Web API backend and client applications in both Blazor WebAssembly and .NET MAUI. The authentication flow is based on JWT with rotating refresh tokens; access tokens expire after 3 minutes and refresh tokens after 30 days. We use GraphQL with a single endpoint for the server-client protocol.
On the client side, tokens are stored in the browser's local storage for web clients and in secure storage for MAUI. Despite being common, storing tokens in local storage is often advised against due to security concerns. The recommended approach is to use HttpOnly cookies, but this solution doesn't fit our requirements for several reasons:
Single Endpoint Issue: Normally, using HttpOnly cookies for refresh tokens would require a separate endpoint (e.g., "/api/refresh"), but we are constrained to a single GraphQL endpoint.
Client Compatibility: HttpOnly cookies are primarily suited for web clients and not for native applications across different platforms (Windows, iOS, Android).
Security Considerations: Storing both the access and refresh tokens in local storage poses security risks, and switching to a single rotating token would require frequent authorization checks against the database, increasing server load.
Question: What is the best way to store access and long-lived refresh tokens that is secure yet functional across both web and native clients, considering the limitations of GraphQL and the need for a protocol-agnostic solution? Any advice on strategies or architectures that cater to this kind of setup would be greatly appreciated.

httponly cookie = CSRF vulnerability... local storage = XSS vulnerability.  Pick your poison.  Since you'll always need to secure against XSS anyway and requiring a custom header for authorization at all your endpoints would protect against CSRF.  You could argue that local storage + requiring custom header is actually more secure.  Native apps don't have to worry about CSRF, and should be able to read cookie responses and store them securely in their own secure storage.

having said that I use httponly cookies myself along with antiforgery tokens which are sent on every request as non-httponly cookies and read from frontend.  (This helps guard against CRIME/BREACH attacks)


There is no cross-platform secure local storage, you'll need to use the best available solution in each client
GraphQL is a red herring as far as your problem goes - you can pass in the access and/or refresh tokens in the request headers from any client platform and your GraphQL context function in your server can extract these headers and auth your request.


My concern is not a native device's storage, but rather a browser's.
And the more I explore this topic the more I realize there is no silver bullet.
Http-Only cookies are HTTP protocol-specific standards, that I try to avoid, prior to creating a platform and protocol-agnostic authentication flow. And a local storage is vulnerable to XSS attacks. So it is really a "pick your poison" situation as it was stated above by  @browsermator

A few additional points to ensure token security:

On the client side, store JWT tokens in encrypted form.
If the client uses a static IP, then you can write it into a JWT token and use it when checking it on the server.
Security-related code can be further protected, for example, obfuscated in JS.
More imagination: enter additional control fields into the request with hashes and ciphers for transmitted data. You can use a device fingerprint, etc.


none of these options will add proper security. The only client-side thing you would want to do would be generate a PKCE (Proof Key for Code Exchange) to help secure token exchange.  Never rely on obfuscation to protect secrets.
